# Crazy behaviour of URISyntaxException

Tags: java, url, encoding, apache-httpclient-4.x, url-encoding

When I try to execute get request using apache http client

```
http://www.shutterstock.com/cat.mhtml?searchterm=иь
```

it works perfect, but when I try

```
http://www.shutterstock.com/cat.mhtml?searchterm=ь
```

I get `URISyntaxException`

Full stack trace as screenshot because I can't paste second symbol after Ñ:

[image: stack trace]

Another successful urls:

```
http://www.shutterstock.com/cat.mhtml?searchterm=сиськи
http://www.shutterstock.com/cat.mhtml?searchterm=сиськиа
http://www.shutterstock.com/cat.mhtml?searchterm=сись
http://www.shutterstock.com/cat.mhtml?searchterm=ф
```

Another failed urls:

```
http://www.shutterstock.com/cat.mhtml?searchterm=сиськиаа
http://www.shutterstock.com/cat.mhtml?searchterm=брей
http://www.shutterstock.com/cat.mhtml?searchterm=фф
```

What the hell is going on?

**I tried** both `URI.create` and `URLEncoder.encode` for url encoding.

With URLEncoder.encode my urls looks like:

```
http://www.shutterstock.com/cat.mhtml?searchterm=%D1%8C
```

but I get exactly the same exception.

Comment: See [RFC 3986 § 2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2). Cyrillic characters are not allowed in an URI...

Comment: Брей сиськи - это правильно

Comment: @BoristheSpider I wrote that I used URLEncoder.encode so I tried to execute `http://www.shutterstock.com/cat.mhtml?searchterm=%D1%8C` with the same result

Comment: @KaPaHgaIII if you encode then pass to the constructor, you end up with [this problem](http://blog.stackhunter.com/2014/03/31/encode-special-characters-java-net-uri/) - i.e. double encoding.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I am not doing double encoding, I tried either URLEncoder.encode or URI.create

Comment: I've just found the root cause of my problem. It is hidden in one word: **redirect**

Answer (score 0):

I found why the problem occurs:

When there are no images matching my request, shutterstock redirects me to `/search-zero` page, overwise it stays at `/cat.mhtml`.

So what I need is to implement my own redirect handler.